# Jar file created by Maven does not have project code

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to make an executable jar with dependancies using Maven. And have tried making the jar with commands:

```
mvn clean assembly:single
mvn clean compile assembly:single
mvn clean compile package assembly:single
```

I get the jar, but it does not have the project code. Could please point me in the right direction. My POM build section is below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>My.Full.Path.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "project code"? What exactly is there, what isn't, and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: Have you tried 'assembly:assembly' ?

Comment: Do you mean the jar file doesn't execute anything?
You didn't do: <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
Check the manifest if your main-class is the same, If it is check if you path to your main entry point is actually correct. Then check if your dependencies are all there.

Comment: is `My.Full.Path.Main` the correct directory structure to where your main class is?

Comment: What I mean by project code is all my java files in the project, my main, my other java files are not in the jar file. And when I try and run it, I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: and yes My.Full.Path.Main is correct

Comment: Show us your project structure (src dir etc)

Comment: Ok checked and my structure is nothing like what maven expects. So I guess I should be asking, how do I tell Maven where to look for my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project has non-standard directory layout, tell maven where is your source code located.

### Maven configuration for custom directory layout (pom.xml)

```
<build>     
   <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   <testResources>
     <testResource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
     </testResource>
   </testResources>
</build>
```

Replace directory location (like `src/main/java`) with your project source location.

### Additional source directories

If your existing project has more `src` directory, then you can use [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>some directory</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

### Building

To build properly configured project use command

```
 mvn package
```